# ios programatically change app icon during build process

Tags: ios, xcode, jenkins, bamboo

I'd like to programmatically change the Icon's for each build.  We use Bamboo so, during our major releases, we want to change the icon's of the application that has a "new" banner on it, and then during a later time remove that banner, thus changing the image icons.

I think it's possible that I could dynamically change the Contents.json that contains references to all of the images (and variants of sizes) inside that file and replace the images (during the build) with the replaced images.

Any ideas on implementation?  I'm also wondering about if I may need to even touch the project.pbxproj file.

This same similar change could be used for using the exact same codebase, but for different application releases.

It's more of a build process feature.  I don't want to change the app icon on the fly after it's already deployed.

Comment: The location of the Contents.json and the images are located at: <project_dir>/Images.xcassets/App.appiconset

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/HazAT/badge I have used that with Fastlane, but no reason it shouldn't also work with Bamboo.

Comment: Impressive I will.  Thanks.  And it appears to be integrated into fastlane.  I'll have to move to that...

Comment: You could create a new Target in XCode, duplicating the existing one (right click on Target in XCode, choose Duplicate).  Then you could have one AppIcon Asset file for Target A, and a different one for Target B.